# Ruby on Rails: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to enable mySQL for my Ruby on Rails application. I generated a model for `Project` in Rails, used `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, and it added all fields required to `myapp_dev` database (mySQL). But when I go to `localhost:3000/projects`, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__93413930__call__216979767__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

What is the problem here? 
Here is my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_dev
  username: root
  password: root
  host: localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting 'dev' section on the top of database.yml:

```
dev:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_dev
  username: root
  password: root
  host: localhost
```

and leave 'development' section as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, your MySql db connection is not working, try to login to your my sql server with following command

```
mysql -uroot -proot myapp_dev
```

Make sure this works, if this works your app also should be able to access the DB, If you get any error, posting the error here will get someone to help you

cheers

Comment: getting mysql command line doesnt necessarily say your database connection is working, having mysql in the command line says your my sql is running, so pls run the above command and let us know the response